# How to make sure the prediction time image input is in the same range as the training time image input?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

This question is about ensuring the prediction time input images to be in the same range as the images fed during the training time. I know that it's the usual practice to repeat the same steps that were done during the training time to process an image at the prediction time. But in my case, I apply `random_trasnform()` function inside a custom data generator during the training time, which won't make sense to add during the prediction time.

---

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
```

To simplify my problem, assume I'm doing the following changes to a grayscale image that I read in a custom data generator.

`img_1` is an output of the data generator, that is supposed to be the input to a VGG19 model.

```
# using a simple augmenter
augmenter = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    brightness_range=(0.75, 1.25),
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input  # preprocessing function of VGG19
)

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('sphx_glr_plot_camera_001.png')
# add a random trasnform
img_1 = augmenter.random_transform(img)/255
```

The above `random_tranform()` has made the grayscale value distribution to be as follows (between [0,1]):

```
plt.imshow(img_1); plt.show();
sns.histplot(img_1[:, :, 0].ravel());  # select the 0th layer and ravel because the augmenter stacks 3 layers of the grayscale image to make it an RGB image
```

[image]

Now, I want to do the same in the prediction time, but, I don't want a random transform applied to the image so I just pass the input image through the `preprocessing_function()`.

```
# read image
img = cv2.imread('sphx_glr_plot_camera_001.png')
# pass through the preprocessing function
img_2 = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(img)/255
```

But I'm unable to make the input to be in the range of the [0, 1] as was done during the training.

```
plt.imshow(img_2); plt.show();
sns.histplot(img_2[:, :, 0].ravel());
```

[image]

This makes the predictions completely incorrect. How can I make sure that the inputs to the model at the prediction time undergo the same steps so that they end up having a similar distribution to the inputs that were fed during training? I don't want to add a `random_transform()` at the prediction time as well.

Comment: Image used: https://scipy-lectures.org/_images/sphx_glr_plot_camera_001.png

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to add an [`per image standardization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) in your model this will ensure you that the mean of the image is 0 and standard deviation is 1 in you training set and in your inference